# Update Config File at design time when adding a reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config, service-model

I have a DLL that references a web service. I would like to automatically add the ServiceModel element to the config file when you add a reference to the dll. Is that even possible?

I know that when you add certain things to your project, this is done.

Thanks,

Comment: If this were part of a nuget package, this could be done.

Comment: @techvice - I am going to try that. I just downloaded the tools to create a nuget package. Where should I look to be able to edit the config file when the package is imported? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in comments that you plan to try a nuget package, you'll want to read up on [transforming files](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations). If you want to have an example to build off of, grab the source for a nuget package I manage ([ErrorHandlerMvc](https://github.com/techvice/ErrorHandlerMvc)). It handles a web.config transformation within it.

If you have the [nuget executable](http://nuget.codeplex.com/downloads/get/922467), you will build the .nuspec file and that takes care of everything else.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! It looks like I will need to put together a Nuget Feed/Gallery service internally, as I don't want to share these packages with the outside world. I will follow up on Monday. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I actually mentioned this earlier today. You can setup Nuget Package Manager to use a folder as a package source. At my current company, we use a network folder (from a build machine) and place nuget packages for internal use there. In Visual Studio, Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Nuget Manager Settings -> Package Sources -> Add package source. Add in a network drive and have all other developers do the same. Place packages there and you are set. You can even have a build machine update these packages (post-build steps).